# Data defined label position for more than one scale in one layer

Tags: qgis, labeling, scale

I'm looking for a better labeling-solution for my projects. It seems to be difficult - but maybe I'm just blind?

My projects:
I build  printed bike-hike-books. The main scale is 1:75k and there are a city scale of 10k and a overview scale of 200k. Because I like to have a "cartographic" quality of labels placements, I touch every single label and move it to it's best position. I have to do this **for every single scale** so my labeling columns for 3 scales look like this ('scale 1' stands for 10k 'scale 2' for 75k  and 'scale 3' for 200k):

[image]

But before I try to explain in detail, I build this simple Example-Project where you can see and test my (old) labeling solution for 3 scales: http://www.map-site.de/tmp/LabelingExample.zip

Well, it is working but:

- You need labeling columns for every scale
- You need a layer for every scale

I'm looking for a much better solution without duplicate layers and tons of columns. I count on your creative minds!

EDIT: I added this two very dense map as examples:

[image]

There is only one single possible position for "St. Paulus Dom" and it's not any quadrant:
[image]

Every label has to be moved manually. Some of the labels are not in a quadrant.

Comment: Do the labels need to accomplish some specific criteria? I don't understand what you mean with "best position".

Comment: With "best position" I mean a position according to cartographic claims. It's more subjective.

Comment: I found that your example uses a font, 'Noto Sans', that I do not have, and I'm guessing that will be the case for others as well. You can download the font here https://www.google.com/get/noto/ After installing the fonts you have to restart QGIS.

Comment: Thanks for adding that link - it's the standard font of my Mint installation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to say that what you are requesting is complicated a little bit because you want the labeling to be visible at small scale clearly as well as at large scale (best fit). So, the idea here is how to place the point that can be visible at different scales.

After several testing, I found that instead of creating several columns for each scale range and put coordinates for x and y at fixed points, you can create only one column for priority positions for each point for best location, as you can see below (I followed the locations in your file):

[image]

Then, you go to `Layer propoerties -> Labels -> Placement -> Offset from point` or `Around point`, both  are OK, but I chose `Offset from point`.

1. At `Quadrant` Select `Data defined override -> Edit`, and enter the
   following formula:

   [image]

   ```
   CASE 
   WHEN  $scale >= 200000 THEN  "priority"  
   WHEN  $scale < 200000 and $scale >= 75000 THEN  "priority"   
   WHEN  $scale < 75000 and $scale >=10000 THEN  5
   WHEN  $scale < 10000 THEN 2 
   END
   ```

   Here, `"Priority"` is the location of points defined in the field name `Priority`
2. You need to use offset to shift the points for better visibility, and I used the following formula:

   ```
   CASE
   WHEN  $scale >= 200000 THEN '0.001,0'
   WHEN  $scale < 200000 and $scale >= 75000 THEN '0.001,0'
   WHEN  $scale < 75000 and $scale >=10000 THEN '0.0005,0'
   WHEN  $scale < 10000 THEN '0.0001,0'
   END
   ```

Here is the output at different scales:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In order to see what each number [0-8] represents in which location, please have a look at following image:

[image]

You can control the position of the labels by adding the value corresponding with each position. But unfortunately, you cannot do it by 'click-and-move' approach. You need to do it in the attribute table.

**Update:**

Based on your requirement that 9 quadrant positions are not enough, I found if you select `Cartography` instead of `Offset from point`, and select priority, as in the image below, you will have 12 priority positions instead of 9. You need to create a field of `Text` type, then put only the abbreviation that you want for the best position 'TL', 'TSL', 'T'...etc. Also, you can enter a distance to avoid the label from covering the point.

[image]

Comment: Thats a approach I did not try until now. Do you see any way, to place the label in the quadrant by 'click-and-move'?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do it by 'click-and-move' approach. You need to do it in the attribute table. But adding 1 column is better than 6 columns for each x,y scale levels. I updated my answer.

Comment: In the last days, I also tried to give a solution but I gave up because I thought the problem was too subjective for offering a more general solution. Instead, the solution by @ahmadhanb seems _creative_ enough for doing it (I didn't test it, though). +1 for me.

Comment: I agree with you. The subjectivity here is high. It is mainly a personal opinion on how you can judge the locations of labels if they are suitable or not.

Comment: @ahmadhanb: right! But - I'm sorry for being so niggling - just 9 quadrants are not enough for special situations like "St. Paulus Dom" in the first example map of my post. In that case I still need the ability for free placement - that means, for this raw cases I still need 6 columns for every layer. (BTW: the Database is huge - having more columns, results in longer loading-times)

Comment: @MAP Another option is to control the font size based on scale similar to what I did in Quadrant to avoid the labels from covering each other. You may decrease the font size when zooming out for example.

Comment: I also found, that the cartographic labeling with priority settings is more suitable for my claims. I tested it and I can work with it very well! Only problem: using the identify-tool to edit the priority-attribute takes up to 5 seconds to open the input mask (this can be annoying by 500 labels).

Comment: Do not  use identify tool to edit the priority locations, it is better to use select tool. Open the attribute table, and choose only to show selected points. Start editing session, and update the location and save edits. The priority location will be updated directly, if you already added the expression in the Data defined override.

Comment: All that ideas and tips made my labeling work much easier and faster. So I can definitely say, that this answer is worth the 100 reputation points!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of the multiple layers by using expressions.

From what I could see in your example the main difference between the layers is the `Data defined Coordinate X Y` definitions pointing to the different scale x,y values.

You can accomplish this in a single layer by selecting the dropdowns next to X and Y and selecting edit... which will bring up an expression string builder.

For X you can use something like

```
if(@map_scale <=10000, "scale1-x", if(@map_scale <=75000, "scale2-x", "scale3-x"))
```

And for Y you can use something like

```
if(@map_scale <=10000,  "scale1-y" , if(@map_scale <=75000, "scale2-y", "scale3-y"))
```

This should use scale1 x,y values if the map scale is less than or equal to 1:10,000 and scale 2 x,y if the map scale is less than or equal to 1:75,000 and scale 3 x,y for anything above that.

If you have to manually position for each scale I don't see how you can get away from scale#-x and scale#-y columns for each level you have defined.

Comment: I have a high destiny of labels with different weight. I have to place them manually since no automatism is able to do it in a 'real' cartographic way. And the maps will be printed and updated every year so the labeling have to be  somewhat static. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartographic_labeling#Placement

Comment: @MAP OK, so you know you have to manually position items, you just want less layers and columns.

Comment: This helps for displaying the labels of 3 scales with just one layer. But QGIS is not able to "write back" coordinates via expression. So If I use the scale-expression as you mentioned, I can not move the labels any more.