# How to place labels for varying projects?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a data set of features in a historic landscape. So if I make a map of it at a certain scale, I then need to move the feature labels around a bit—tweak them—to make it look nice.

But then if I do another  project to make another map of a smaller portion of the area—an enlargement at a larger scale—the labels again need adjusting—they need to be moved a bit to make it look good in that view.

However, if I then go back to my first project to revise that, all my label positions are messed up. Apparently the label location data goes with the original data. Seems like it would be better if label location adjustments like this were stored in a file with the project, so you could use the data for various projects at different scales.

Am I missing something? Is there a different way I should be doing this? The only resolution I can think of would be to make duplicate data sets for various projects using different scales.

Comment: I think your question is similar to this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229686/data-defined-label-position-for-more-than-one-scale-in-one-layer/230138#230138

Comment: Depends a bit what QGIS Version you are using.  Since 3.x label position will be stored in the auxilary storage, which goes with the project (the new project format *.qgz is a zip format containing 2 files, the *.qgs and the auxilary storage file). See more information e.g. here: https://oslandia.com/en/2017/10/17/auxiliary-storage-support-in-qgis-3/

Comment: Thanks. 

Version 3 gave me problems, so I am still using 2.18.

The method detailed in the link provided looks a bit over my head, so I just made a duplicate data set for use at large scale.